# Bounds on eigenvalues/trace/singular values of a matrix based on trace/Frobenius norm etc.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, upper-lower-bounds, spectral-radius, spectral-norm

**Background:** Given an $M\times P$ matrix $B^{(R)}$ with elements $B^{(R)}_{m,p}=f_R(X_1,\dots,X_M)$ and $X_m$ are random variables (for simplicity Gaussian i.i.d) and $f_R$ is a function parameterized by $R$. (Note that $B$ is a finite random matrix but the entries are a function of the random variables and since there are only $M$ of them, some of them will be dependent).
Consider the Gram matrix $A^{(R)} = (B^{(R)})^T B^{(R)}$. I can clearly observe numerically that $\operatorname{Tr}((A^{(R_1)})^{-1}) \leq \operatorname{Tr}((A^{(R_2)})^{-1})$. In words, for a given $R$, one matrix structure is better than the other one. This is what I want to proof. It not only holds for the trace but also the minimum eigenvalue of $A^{(R)}$, the determinant and condition number of $(A^{(R)})^{-1}$.

**My idea:** Without inverting a matrix, calculating its eigenvalues or its determinant, I can calculate any property that's linear, because I can just push the expectation operator in. So it's "easy" to obtain $\mathbb{E}\operatorname{Tr}A^{(R)}$ or $\mathbb{E}\|A^{(R)}\|_F$. But any nonlinear transformation makes it hard to get the expected value. Hence my idea is to bound any of the properties of its inverse for a given $R_1$ and $R_2$ so that I can proof that matrix with $R_1$ is always better than $R_2$.

**Question:** I want to show that
$$
\mathbb{E}g(A^{-1}) \leq \mathbb{E} f(A) ,
$$

where

- $f$ is a linear function of $A$ so I can relate to the expected value of its components $A_{p,q}$ (which I know analytically)
- $g$ is one of the following: $\operatorname{Tr}$, $\operatorname{det}$, $\lambda_{\max}$

Does something like this exist?
Note that a valid answer would also be "No, it does not exist" (preferably with an explanation why).

Comment: Highly unlikely. For $n=1$, you're asking for $|a|\le f(1/|a|)$. Secondly, a pds matrix has its invariant info in its eigenvalues, so the question is about $\sum_i\lambda_i\le f(\lambda_i^{-1})$. The AM-GM string of inequalities shows that, if anything, the inequalities run the other way; in fact $\|A^{-1}\|\mathrm{tr}(A)\ge n\sqrt{n}$ is true (where the norm is Frobenius).

Comment: Having said that, I think $\lambda_{min}\le\|A^{-1}\|^{-1/2}\sqrt{n}$ is true. I can give an answer along these lines.

Comment: Hmm, these are good (but frustrating) points. I think your 2nd suggestion *could* help me. Let me add first: $A^{-1}$ is a finite random matrix with a certain structure. My goal is to find any spectral properties of $A$ (trace preferred). So I would need to be able to wrap the expectation operator around the whole inequality and calculate the expression based on the matrix elements. Would this work? $$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{(\lambda_{\min}(A))^2}\right] \geq n \mathbb{E}\left[\|A^{-1}\|_F\right] $$ ? (the right side I could calculate based on the elements of $A^{-1}$

Comment: I also want to add my context: I have two finite random matrices with a similar structure. I want to proof that on average, one of them has better spectral properties than the other

Comment: Another remark: I'm afraid it would need to be $\lambda_{\max}(A)$... or $\lambda_{\min}(A^{-1})$ Does anything cross your mind on the latter?

Comment: $\lambda_{max}(A)$ and $\lambda_{min}(A^{-1})$ are reciprocals of each other. 'Unfortunately' $\lambda_{max}(A)\ge \mathrm{Tr}(A)/n$ so it's even worse with it. I would suggest you post or alter the question with the original problem.

Comment: I updated my question. Maybe it's easier where I am coming from. An answer showing that it's just not possible to show would be sad but also acceptable.